# Flex library not loaded

Tags: magento, cpanel

In Magento admin panel I get the message "Flex library not loaded" when I want to edit a product. This is since the upgrade from Magento 1.7 to 1.8.1.
I am able to edit the product, but it won´t save the change.
Task in this micro-project is to fix this error. It shouldn´t pop-up anywhere in the admin panel any more when doing the management of the webshop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

What is the permission of your /js/lib directory ? Please try to assign full permissions and check it again.

Comment: i already changed the permission to 777 but still that shows the same error

Comment: When entering into my Magento back office, I get the error "flex library not downloaded." I have already granted permissions to the js/lib folder without results. This is not letting me adjust categories or add products